# how can one setup a bandwidth control on a local network?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, router, webserver, bandwidth

I want to setup bandwidth control for our network, by using a 'main' computer as the hub to manage bandwidths of other computers connected to the same network.

Also, I have a dedicated IP with my internet provider, and would like to use the main computer as the server, and all other computer as networked devices. So when users access the IP, the Ubuntu server on the main computer gets accessed.

Comment: First read up on [Subnetting](http://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-ipv4-subnetting-work) and routing. Then consider creating two local networks: One "Lan with everything except the modem" connected to a NIC on the Ubuntu server. The other with the servers second NIC and the modem. Note that NO internet access will be possible if the server computer is turned off.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to limit your Internet bandwidth usage with your Ubuntu gateway you could use  [wondershaper](http://lartc.org/wondershaper/).

Here's a nice and [quick tutorial](http://linuxadministration.us/easy-ubuntu-traffic-shaping/) on how to do it with wondershaper.

You could use also a more network oriented distribution such as [pfSense](http://pfsense.org/) (FreeBSD based) or [OpenWRT](https://openwrt.org/) instead of Ubuntu for your gateway.